# Buffered versus unbuffered output for Python in Windows

Tags: python, notepad++, nppexec, unbuffered-output

I use NppExec/Notepad++ to run Python scripts, and flush my output buffers continuously during runtime to update my console window with `print` statements (The default buffered output only shows *all* print statements after the script finishes execution).

[This](https://superuser.com/questions/381942/stop-nppexec-from-trapping-console-output-until-program-finishes) link shows that all you need to do is use the command `python -u` to get unbuffered output. Is there a downside to using this execution mode for **all** my Python scripts, *regardless of the editor used*? I'm not clear about the difference between a buffered an unbuffered output.

**EDIT**: I included this small Python timer script for an example:

```
#!usr/bin/env python
import time
import threading
import sys

class Timer(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, seconds):
        self.runTime = seconds
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    def run(self):
        counter = self.runTime
        for sec in range(self.runTime):
            print counter
            time.sleep(1.0)
            counter -= 1
        print "Done."

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = Timer(10)
    t.start()
```

How much difference does a buffered and unbuffered output make in terms of efficiency in this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Buffered output means that the computer spools the output somewhere in memory until a certain amount has accumulated.  Then it writes the entire block at once.  This is more efficient than using unbuffered output which writes the output as soon as you request for it to be written.

The downside is that your programs will run a little (or a lot) slower depending on how much output you're writing.  If they're short programs which don't do too much output, you're unlikely to notice a difference...

**EDIT**

buffered vs. unbuffered output isn't only a python question.  The same concepts (and terms) apply to other languages as well.  In lower level languages it becomes even more important in some ways -- If I write messages in a C program using buffered output, and then my program dies because of a programming error, any of the data that was spooled before the error, but not written to disk is lost.  That's not such a problem because it is reasonably difficult to get the python interpreter to abort on an error -- even if your code is bad, the interpreter still cleans up alright in the end...(unless you send a kill signal to it or something)...

Comment: could you elaborate a little more on 'short' and 'long' programs please? Is it related to floating point operations, iterations, algorithm complexity, or the *number* of print commands I place? I also edited my question

Comment: @prrao It would be related to the number of print commands -- The number of bytes you're writing out at a time.  In your example, the time.sleep function will take *WAY* longer to complete than your IO ever would since it's only 1 print statement.  So, for that example, unbuffered IO is fine.  In general though, the easiest way to tell is to time it (use the `timeit` module) and see if there is any noticable difference.

Answer (score 5):

I can think of two downsides but how significant they are depends upon your needs:

1. Unbuffered reading and writing may be significantly slower; if you're writing a text file one line at a time, your code may make hundreds more system calls to ask the OS to write the file. Depending upon the speed in which you're writing to disk, this may even mean that the last block of the file needs to be re-read from disk in order to re-save the file with a new last line. (This might be rare; but more system calls are almost always a recipe for going slower.)

   Here's a simple demonstration of the number of system calls having a large influence on write speed:

   ```
   $ cat initrd.img-2.6.38-8-generic > /dev/null
   ```

   The first line makes sure the file is in cache, so only *output* speed is being measured.

   ```
   $ dd if=initrd.img-2.6.38-8-generic of=/tmp/out bs=16 oflag=dsync
   ^C262766+0 records in
   262766+0 records out
   4204256 bytes (4.2 MB) copied, 50.7754 s, 82.8 kB/s
   ```

   I gave up waiting for this -- it's going way too slow. This is "unbuffered" writing 16 bytes at a time to disk, and making sure each write succeeded before moving on to the next. (That's the `dsync` -- more on that later.)

   ```
   $ dd if=initrd.img-2.6.38-8-generic of=/tmp/out bs=$((4096)) oflag=dsync
   3218+1 records in
   3218+1 records out
   13181130 bytes (13 MB) copied, 3.69961 s, 3.6 MB/s
   $ dd if=initrd.img-2.6.38-8-generic of=/tmp/out bs=$((4096 * 10)) oflag=dsync
   321+1 records in
   321+1 records out
   13181130 bytes (13 MB) copied, 0.471143 s, 28.0 MB/s
   ```

   These two commands show the effect of some buffering -- the first one writes data in 4096-byte chunks, which might be what the default buffering gives you. This is roughly fifty times faster than 16 bytes at a time. The second command is writing data in 40960 byte chunks, and it went roughly nine times faster *still*. (All told, it's roughly 345 times faster to write 40960 bytes at a time than 16 bytes at a time.)

   If your data is small, this won't really matter. After all, it won't take much time either way. If your data is large, it might matter more, depending upon how much data you're writing at once and how often it lines up on happy "byte boundaries" for the underlying devices.
2. Some protocols on sockets may change their behavior based on the *timing* of the data you're sending. If you're building data incrementally, you may send partial data in a single packet and a packet-based receiver may not handle this gracefully. (It's harder for me to imagine a TCP-based system with this problem other than driving a game of some sort; a UDP-based system is far easier to imagine having a problem with this.)

Comment: Your example went a little above my head! Could you look at my question edit and explain in terms of that please? thanks for the detailed response!

Comment: I'm not really clear about "data is small or large". Does this mean *number of lines* I'm printing out? I run all my Python files locally through my console

Comment: OK I think I have my question answered. THanks!

Comment: Hah, once again showing the importance of asking for more context. Your code is _so small_ and does so little that performance does not really matter -- but the correctness _does_. You could get your program to work correctly by adding flush commands immediately after the `print` statement, but honestly, it'd work identically. Just use the `-u` and be happy. :)

Comment: I'm taking away the moral that if my code run time is *far greater* than the time taken to print a few update lines to notify the user of run progress, I can safely use `python -u` without any worries. Hope I'm correct here

Comment: It depends more upon the _kinds_ of things your code would do; if it is doing a lot of disk IO, you might wish to add explicit flush operations to your user status messages. If it is all compute-bound or, better still, idle as you have here, then all-unbuffered is fine.